# Force MySQL to write back

Tags: php, mysql, solr

I have an issue where an instance of Solr is querying my MySQL database to refresh its index immediately after an update is made to that database, but the Solr query is not seeing the change made immediately prior.

I imagine the problem has to be something like Solr is using a different database connection, and somehow the change is not being "committed" (I'm not using transactions, just a call to `mysql_query`) before the other connection can see it. If I throw a sufficiently long `sleep()` call in there, it works *most* of the time, but obviously this is not acceptable.

Is there a PHP or MySQL function that I can call to force a write/update/flush of the database before continuing?

Comment: Do you use a master/slave config?

Comment: I have no idea, I didn't set this up. Presumably though, the index is built off of a master MySQL database.

Answer (score 1):

You might make Solr use [SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL = READ-COMMITTED](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/set-transaction.html) to get more prompt view of updated data.

You should be able to do this with the transactionIsolation property of the JDBC URL.

Comment: I tried adding `&transactionIsolation=TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED` to the connection string url but I can't tell if it's having any effect. Can you be a bit more explicit, I'm new to a lot of this.